# Runtime error '800a000d' with asp code

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I receive the following error when I do a search on the website for items in the database.

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'FormatCurrency'
/search_diamond_results.asp, line 657
```

Line 657 has the following code.

```
'profprice = 0

                                price = 0 

                                price = rst("price")
                                'profprice = rst("profit") / 100                 

                                totprice = price' + profprice 


                                'If rst("profit") <> "" then
                    657--->             prc = FormatCurrency(totprice)
                                'Else
                                    If rst("price") <> "" then
                                        prc = FormatCurrency(rst("price")) 
                                    'Else
                                        'prc = rst("price") 
                                    End if
                                'End If
```

Do you have a solution to the above error?

Comment: You need to ensure that your `price` actually contains a value and ensure that the value returned to it is correct.  I find a quick and dirty method of `price = CDbl("0" & rst(price))` usually covers it.

Comment: Have you looked at this post?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464347/microsoft-vbscript-runtime-error-800a000d-800a000d?rq=1    They had the same error so may give you some clues

Answer (score 0):

Probably your **totprice** is empty or is a string, you must assign a value to use **FormatCurrency**
to check if your variable is a string, just use **IsNumeric(var)** it will return true or false.
Also, be sure of that price is not a varchar in the database.

```
price = rst("price")
if IsNumeric(price)=false then
    price=replace(price,".",",")
    price=formatnumber(price)
end if
'profprice = rst("profit") / 100                 
totprice = price ' + profprice 
'If rst("profit") <> "" then
    prc = FormatCurrency(totprice)
'Else
    If rst("price") <> "" then
        prc = FormatCurrency(rst("price")) 
    'Else
        'prc = rst("price") 
    End if
'End If
```

Comment: which line now? are you sure that **totprice** is not a string or empty?

Comment: Its the same line of code. The information should be pulling from the database.

Comment: Totprice is a set of numbers. How can I check ?

Comment: I updated my answer, so use **IsNumeric(totprice)** to check if it's numeric o not,

Comment: so, it's a string and you can't use FormatCurrency with a string.

Comment: How can i display the contents of the varchar in the database ?

Comment: I used the function isNull and it returned true

Comment: are you using varchar in the database?! that's why you get the error!!! varchar is a string! change it to float or numeric value.

Comment: It's a float in the database. I working through someone elses code and the default value of the Price_Carat field is null however i see prices in the table. Where can i find where they are correlating the price from the database to the code ?

Comment: I don't know your code or your DB. But I edited my answer again. Check it.

Comment: I received the following error. Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a005e'
Invalid use of Null: 'Replace'

Comment: Why not just `If Len(price & "") > 0 And IsNumeric(price & "") Then price = CDbl(price) Else price = 0`?

Comment: Can you skype me to fix error ? I will pay 10.00 if you can complete it.

Comment: Lankymart is right, but anyway you must check and fix the value you require from the DB.